# Regular expression to match 1.* only

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried various regular expression but can't get this one quite right.

I need to match `1.*` so that means it has to be a 1 followed by a dot and any **1 or 2 digit** number following the dot.

So examples of valid matches:

```
1.8
1.9
1.11
1.99
```

Invalid:

```
2.1
9.19
1.111
```

Comment: `^1\.[0-9]{1,2}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is `1\.\d{1,2}$`. Try the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7mS5rr/1) on Regex101.com.

To split it out:
`1` - matches literal number one.
`\.` - matches literal dot character (you need the escape slash)
`\d` - matches any number character (it's culture invariant, so it's not only 0-9 characters - if you want only these, use `[0-9]` as comments to your question suggest)
`{1,2}` - is a quantifier applied to `\d` - minimum 1 occurence, maximum 2 occurences
`$` - anchors the text to the end of the string/line (depending whether multiline regex option is set to true)

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty simple:

```
^1\.\d{1,2}$
```

Explanation:

```
^     Start of Line
1     match 1
\.    match Dot, Dot needs to be escaped, otherwise it will match any Character
\d    match a Digit
{1,2} Length of the Digit is 1 to 2 Characters
$     End of Line
```